# Can Rails differentiate between types of parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

Let's say I have a route like so:

```
get 'share/:ftp/:id' => 'share#show', :as => :share
```

Can I get Rails to recognise whether a user has typed an `:id` or another different kind of variable? So if a user types a certain string in it'll find records based on that? Something like this (pseudocode):

```
get 'share/:ftp/:id || share/:ftp/:string' => 'share#show', :as => :share
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It seems what you need are routing constraints. Check this out: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#segment-constraints

Comment: Rails already does this. `:id` will match essentially anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow either id or string in route, you don't need change on route, just use a more flexible alternative to `find`.

```
# routes.rb
get 'share/:ftp/:id' => 'share#show', :as => :share # No change.

# ShareController
@share = Share.find_param(params[:id]) # Call a custom method

# Share model
# Suppose your "string" is the name
class Share < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.find_param(input, param='name')
    input.to_i == 0 ? send("find_by_#{param}" : super
  end
end
```

Comment: Oh, ha: should be `to_i`.

Comment: Ah, yes, `to_i`, typed too quick

Comment: Please do not override `find` within Active Record, as you're overriding very basic functionality that other code may depend on. Instead, call this method something different.

Comment: @RyanBigg, nice suggestion, I accept that. I read your book of first edition before and just know the second is coming, can't wait to read that!

Comment: Good to hear, @BillyChan :)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you specify constraints, Rails will accepts any type as a parameter. Format constraint looks like `get '/:id', to: 'posts#show', constraints: {id: /^\d/}` More about constraints here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#segment-constraints